# What are similar class for below objects in Harmony OS?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, harmonyos

Please help me for similar classes for 1. AppBarLayout, 2.Interpolator(with setInterpolator method), 3. BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id), 4. SpannableString, 5. ReplacementSpan in HarmonyOS.

Comment: I am also searching for `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id)` nothing found so far..Bitmap = PixelMap btw..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. For Interpolator/setInterpolator try using Animator/AnimatorProperty setCurveType(curveType)

By default it is a linear interpolator but you can set other types as well. Please check -

https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/animatorproperty-0000001054439987#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001054439987__setCurveType-int-

3. For BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id)  : you can use  ImageSource and createPixelmap. Something like-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `BitMapFactory.decodeResource` and `ImageSource.createPixelmap` method classes, No other class can find a similar type in Harmony OS by now.

For details about image decoding, see the following website development guide:
https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/media-image-decoding-0000000000031770?ha_source=hms1

Comment: What is the alternative for the `Handler.postDelayed()` method? @shirley

Comment: ok, found! `getUITaskDispatcher(). delayDispatch()`